# Weird front headphones jack issue

Tags: headphone-jack, front-panel

I seem to be experiencing a weird problem with the front headphone jack of my pc.

It was working fine yesterday until i tripped while have my earphones on which disconnected the jack very roughly.

The problem is that when i fully insert the jack into the hole until it holds perfectly i only hear sound on one side (kinda like a sound balance). If i insert it half way through everything will be back to normal, but this way the cable is loose and any agitation will disconnect it very easily

I tried a few tests, earphones are fine and work well on other pcs. Any headset also reproduces the  same problem when connected to the front panel, **but not the back panel**.

Any ideas what i might have done? and how i can fix it ?

Thanks in advance, your help is very much appreciated

PS: I tried digging in the case but i can't get to the front panel from the inside without disconnecting everything so i'm avoiding that for now.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck here. You may have bumped the internals out of alignment, and considering the cost of a repair versus a replacement, you're probably best off getting a USB sound card for the front, or using the back ports on the PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What probably happened when the plug was yanked out was that one of the connectors came loose/moved. You may be able to fix that, but it's quite unlikely. Your best bet is probably to replace that headphone jack (since it's the front panel that might not be too hard).

[image: Headphone jack] 
Ignore the microphone part, that's irrelevant to you.

Comment: thanks, i do ok with electronics so im gonna follow your advice and try to get the circuit out and replace it, as you said it's not a big circuit but i just have to get it out without breaking anything first :D

Comment: Good luck! You're a braver man than I.