# Windows 10 "vocal cancellation" effect if I am using front case jack with headphones that have a mic

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headphones

This is downright strange. I have some Skull Candy headphones (they have a mic as well) I plug into the front jack of my case. Since yesterday, it's been "voice cancelling" (or just muddying) the audio of all applications (Spotify, Chrome, etc). I've found similar issues elsewhere without any resolution. Things I have tried

- Replugging the headphones (the jack is new and had no [mishaps](https://superuser.com/questions/465630/weird-front-headphones-jack-issue))
- Changing Windows audio settings
- Reinstalling the motherboard-provided drivers

The rear jack works just fine, but is impractical to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around I noticed that if I pulled the headphones out slightly (so the headphone mic ring didn't engage) the effects went away. A friend asked if I had a mute button on my set and it turns out I do (it's not obvious since the button runs the entire length of the mic part). Depressing the mic button again fixed the problem. Apparently Windows doesn't know what to do with the mute.